# How to add a styling argument from object in bquote?

Tags: r, text, expression, styling

I'd like to add a formatted text to a plot using `bquote` like this:

```
var <- LETTERS[1:4]
eq <- bquote(bold(.(var[1])))
plot(1)
text(1,0.8,eq)
```

Actually, I want to set the styling argument (here: bold) from an object:

```
mstyle <- "bold"
var <- LETTERS[1:4]
eq <- bquote(.(mstyle)(.(var[1])))
plot(1)
text(1,0.8,eq)
```

This results in "bold(A)". I've tried multiple combinations of `bquote`, `expression`, `substitute` etc. but I can't get it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `mstyle` is a string rather than a symbol. Wrapping it in `as.symbol()` fixes this:

```r
eq <- bquote(.(as.symbol(mstyle))(.(var[1])))
```

... although there's no longer any point using `bquote()`. You might as well use `call()`:

```r
eq <- call(mstyle, var[1])
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Jeremy. Didn't know about 'call'. Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Another possibility is to use a string and then parse it at the end.

```
mstyle <- "bold"
var <- LETTERS[1:4]

s <- sprintf("%s(%s)", mstyle, var[1])  # "bold(A)"
plot(1)
text(1, 0.8, parse(text = s))
```

**2)** If the entire string is to be bold then we could use face = 2. In general plain is 1, bold is 2, italic is 3, bold-italic is 4 and symbol is 5.

```
face <- 2 # bold
plot(1)
text(1, 0.8, var[1], face = face)
```